# Eclipse export signed apk fails in mac osx 10.5.8

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, apk

I am using MacOSX-10.5.8. I have installed latest version of android sdk.ADT version 20.3.

While exporting signed apk I am getting below error. I am using 64 bit eclipse.

```
Error while running zipalign: dyld:unknown required load command 0x80000022
```

I have gone through some links and tried below command, but its failing.

> Static-112:~ dsr$ gcc-4.2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 isysroot
>   /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/ i686-apple-darwin9-gcc-4.2.1:
>   isysroot: No such file or directory

I tried many ways but could not resolve this problem.

Kindly suggest a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Trace/BPT trap
...chances are the system tries to run a build intended for Snow Leopard.
A workaround you could try is to run Terminal.app and use the arch command like this:

```
arch -i386 /Applications/eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse-bin
```

(Substitute /Application/eclipse.app with the location of the app, and use the name of the executable (ending with -bin) instead of eclipse-bin as necessary.)Hope this helps you.

Comment: I have tried below options but no luck.                        Option1: In android project I couldn't find any bin file. Only .apk file exists.                                                           Option 2: I tried to launch eclipse using i386 option and I am getting below error.                                           Static-112:~ dsr$ arch -i386 Downloads/eclipse/eclipse
arch: posix_spawnp: Downloads/eclipse/eclipse: Bad CPU type in executable

Comment: Did you use “-isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.5' on the build?

Comment: In which path  can we find isysroot?  -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.5
-bash: -isysroot: command not found

Comment: Have you installed gcc?isysroot comes with gcc.

Comment: I have tried the command and getting below error,                            tatic-112:/ dsr$ gcc-4.2 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.5
i686-apple-darwin9-gcc-4.2.1: no input files

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. It seems the zipalign tool is broken on 10.5.8. Luckily, I had an older version of sdk and I copied over its zipalign and it works now. Also the latest zipalign works fine on 10.6.8